# Network Connectivity Issue with Akeyless Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying Akeyless Gateway on kubernetes using Docker Desktop.
And I am facing an issue with network connectivity. Here are the pod logs:

```
Starting up
No network connectivity, using existing artifacts
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:473: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
self.warnings.warn(
2024-03-26 17:22:19,228 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/base-supervisord.conf" during parsing
2024-03-26 17:22:19,228 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/logrotate-cron-supervisord.conf" during parsing
2024-03-26 17:22:19,228 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/rsyslog-supervisord.conf" during parsing
2024-03-26 17:22:19,228 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/splunk-forwader-supervisord.conf" during parsing
2024-03-26 17:22:19,228 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2024-03-26 17:22:19,231 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2024-03-26 17:22:19,231 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2024-03-26 17:22:19,231 INFO supervisord started with pid 14
2024-03-26 17:22:20,233 INFO spawned: 'exit_on_any_fatal' with pid 15
2024-03-26 17:22:20,235 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 16
2024-03-26 17:22:20,236 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 17
2024-03-26 17:22:20,237 INFO spawned: 'splunkforwader' with pid 18
READY
splunkd 269 was not running.
Stopping splunk helpers...
Done.
```

I have allowed all the ingress and egress traffic.
The helm chart that I am using is this: https://github.com/akeylesslabs/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/akeyless-api-gateway

I tried allowing all the ingress and egress traffic.
Checked all the ports.
I tried deploying a standalone gateway using docker, which is working on my local using Docker Desktop.